# How can I implement a custom loss function that takes into account multiple predictions of the network?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I am currently implementing a CNN with a custom error function.
The problem I am trying to solve is physics-based, so I can calculate the maximal achievable precision, or to put it another way, I know the best possible (i.e. minimal) standard deviation I can achieve. Those best possible precisions are calculated during the generation of the training data using the Cramer-Rao-lower bound (CRLB).

Right now, my error function looks something like this (in Keras):

```
def customLoss(yTrue, yPred):
    STD = yTrue[:, 10:20]
    yTrue = yTrue[:, 0:10]
    dev = K.mean(K.abs(K.abs(yTrue - yPred) - STD))
    return dev
```

In this case, I have 10 parameters, so I want to estimate with 10 CRLB's. I put the CRLB's in the target vector just to be able to handle the in the error function.

To my question. This method works, but it is not what I want. The problem is that the error is calculated considering a single prediction of the network, but to be correct the network would have to predict the same dataset/batch multiple times. By doing that I would be able to see the standard deviation of the prediction and use that to calculate the error (I'm using a Bayesian CNN).

Has someone an idea how to implement such a function in Keras or Tensorflow (I would also not mind switching to PyTorch)?

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE! This question is probably more appropriate for Stack Overflow, because this is a programming issue. So I will migrate it to SO. Please, read this https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more details about the type of questions we prefer here.

Comment: Hi @PhilippZelger, can you please elaborate on what you mean by ```the network would have to predict the same dataset/batch multiple times```?, And if possible also include a test data with/without code for your intended output. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is, that in order to calculate the loss properly any batch of training data should be evaluated multiple times (during every training step training). As I use a Bayesian dropout function this gives slightly different results for every evaluation. For the network, I need to calculate the standard deviation to the target value (STD). The mismatch between STD and the CRLB should give me an appropriate loss function. My test data consists of 13x13px images and the target vector basically consists of a normalized 1x10 vector. The CRLB-vector is normalized accordingto the targets